# How to communicate in an application legal right in the country and willingness to relocate?

Tags: resume, united-kingdom, applications, international

I'm a UK citizen but I've been living and working in the US for the last 14 years. Due to changing personal circumstances, I'm looking to move back to the UK but I don't want to relocate unless I already have a job lined up.

All of my professional work experience is in the US and my address is in California so on my CV I look like a US citizen. When applying for jobs om the UK, what is the best way to communicate that I don't require and visa sponsorhip and I am wanting to relocate? How can I make my CV more appealing to a UK employer given I only have work experience in the US?

Comment: (1) Line up top with your name/address stating you are a UK citizen. (2) Up front in your cover letter - "I'm a UK citizen looking to relocate back to the UK" or something similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When applying for jobs in the UK, you can mention in your cover letter or application that you are a UK citizen and are looking to relocate back to the UK. You can also state that you do not require any visa sponsorship. This will help to communicate your situation to the employer and let them know that you are already authorized to work in the UK.

To make your CV more appealing to UK employers, you can focus on highlighting the skills and experience that are transferable to the UK job market. You can emphasize the international experience you have gained while working in the US and how it can benefit the UK organization you are applying to. This can include any experience working with international clients or colleagues, navigating cross-cultural communication, or adapting to new environments and ways of working.

It may also be helpful to tailor your CV and cover letter to the specific job and industry you are applying to in the UK. Research the job market and the company you are applying to, and highlight the skills and experiences that align with their needs and values.

Finally, it may be helpful to network with professionals in the UK to gain insights into the job market and make connections that can help with your job search. Consider reaching out to former colleagues or industry contacts in the UK or joining professional networking groups in your field.

Answer (score 8):

Resumes can have an "objective section" which is your 10 seconds elevator sales pitch. In this that's probably the best choice to communicate your intent

Something like

> UK citizen with extensive overseas experience looking for XZY role in the UK

Some more details and examples for the objective section: https://uk.indeed.com/career-advice/cvs-cover-letters/cv-objectives-examples

Answer (score -1):

Hirers should not ask you about citizenship, but there is nothing to stop you writing

> UK Citizen

on your resume. A slightly more general ways is to write:

> Permitted to work for any employer in the UK

which tells them you are a citizen or a permanent resident or have Indefinite Leave to Remain.

Likewise

> Willing to relocate to the UK

tells them what they need to know.